# param0 disappearing in Soap request in PHP using SoapClient class

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a web service from PHP code using `SoapClient`.

```
$service = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$service->myFunction('something', 'anotherthing', 'onemore');
```

If I turn on trace and get the last request, I can see that the first parameter is always missing from the Soap message, i.e. `param0` is never there. It's the same in functions with less or more parameters.

The Soap request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <myFunction />
    <param1>anotherthing</param1>
    <param2>onemore</param2>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I expect it to be (and what my web service accepts when using soapUI):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <myFunction>
      <param0>something</param0>
      <param1>anotherthing</param1>
      <param2>onemore</param2>
    </myFunction>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It's the same with

```
__soapCall('myFunction', array($something, $anotherthing, $onemore));
```

I am using xampplite on Windows XP.

Update: http://programming.itags.org/php/236781/ is a link to someone with the same problem (posted in 2008 with no answers :( ).

Update 2: I also noticed that it doesn't put the xml elements representing the parameters as child elements of the element representing the function. This can't be right?!!?

I've done a horrible fix where I overload the __doRequest function and edit the $request variable. It works, but it sucks. I might as well compile the entire request myself......

Update 3: To me it feels like PHP is just malfunctioning. But if it was a bug in the soap implementation, I'd think there would be more info on it on the web. aaaargh. Next attempt is to try NuSoap and PEAR.

Update 4: To round it off, I didn't try NuSoap and PEAR. I just went with my 'hack' because it worked and there were other activities that needed doing. Furthermore, the demo has been given and for the next phase PHP will not be used anymore. So the whole thing will be re-implemented anyway.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR version: you're calling your SOAP method incorrectly. Put the parameters in an array, rather than having them as separate arguments for PHP's __call().

I had this same problem, and it was really stumping me. I guessed I just bashed my head against the wall a bit longer though. I found I was doing:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($uri);
$soapclient->MethodName($param0, $param1, $param2);
```

Which curiously, creates SOAP XML like so:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MethodName/>
<param1>$param1</param1>
<param2>$param2</param2>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I should have done was called the method like so:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($uri);
$soapclient->MethodName(array($param0, $param1, $param2));
```

This creates SOAP XML like so:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MethodName>
<param0>$param0</param0>
<param1>$param1</param1>
<param2>$param2</param2>
</MethodName>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In hindsight, kinda obvious - but I can see how I mistook the SOAP parameters for also being the PHP parameters!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This could really have been the cause of the problem. I don't have access to that specific code any more, so it will be difficult to test it. However, if I look in my original text I see I typed that the bug also occurs with this call: "__soapCall('myFunction', array($something, $anotherthing, $onemore));". What am I doing wrong there and do you also get the same bug in that case? If I have time at home, I'll try to set this up again and test it to ensure. I will put it in my Google todo-list :).

Comment: I had tried __soapCall, and with both ordered and associative arrays. From memory it didn't help me - although it now strikes me that yes, you'd expect that to work. (unfortunately all those failed attempts aren't in SVN, so I can't see for sure, heh)

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the SoapClient is sending by extending the [doRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php) method and debugging the `$request` argument.

Alternatively, [SoapClient::__getLastRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) can also be used, but I had some problems in the past when my calls generated an exception (ie: do not comply with the WDSL), in `doRequest` you can inspect the XML prior to sending.

Be assured that passing along arguments works like expected, and that your problem probably lies with the actual variables you are sending, or that the call doesn't match the operation as specified in the WSDL.

Comment: What I meant with get the last request is call __getLastRequest(). I editted my question to show the Soap Request that __getLastRequest() returns. I'll see what doRequest() shows me.

Comment: doRequest reports the same. Makes sense I guess :). However, this has given me the idea to add param0 myself in the doRequest overload. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it suits the elegancy of the problem......... I'll report back if it has worked or not.

Comment: Have you tried a different operation (or better yet, a different WSDL)? Maybe it is this specific operation. You have to determine if the problem lies with the SoapClient, or the WSDL.

Comment: I tested the WSDL in SoapUI and the soap requests SoapUI generates from looking at the WSDL are much better, as in, they work!